# formControlName and input name

Tags: angular

I am making custom for input in my application.

I would like to allow autocompletion, and I saw that to work,

> In order to provide autocompletion, user-agents might require
> // elements to:
>
> ```
> Have a name and/or id attribute
> Be descendants of a <form> element
> The form to have a submit button
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Now, I already pass a formControlName to my input, and I would like to use that has name

```
      <app-input
        [placeholder]="'i18n.Field.AddressSecond.Placeholder' | translate"
        [formControlName]="'addressSecond'"
        [autocomplete]="'address-line2'"
      ></app-input>
```

instead of duplicating the input like this

```
      <app-input
        [placeholder]="'i18n.Field.AddressSecond.Placeholder' | translate"
        [formControlName]="'addressSecond'"
        [name]="'addressSecond'"
        [autocomplete]="'address-line2'"
      ></app-input>
```

Since I also saw that `name` must be equal to `formControlName`...
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40074

But I can7t find a way to retrieve the `formControlName` inside my custom input component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-counter-input',
  templateUrl: './counter-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counter-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CounterInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CounterInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() autocomplete: string;

  disabled = false;


  onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  writeValue(value: number): void {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

}
```

Comment: It might work with `@HostBinding`, but I'm not sure. Also, not sure why you would need to have `name` equal to `formControlName`, they are two completely different things (but could be bug with radio).

Comment: A small suggestion, don't make an Input component. Create a wrapper component, and add directive to `input`. This way you keep direct access to native `input` element, which is way easier to work with to add additional functionality. Take a look at how material form field works, it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the formControlName inside your implementation, just add an input with the name of `formControlName`.

Read more about [here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-a0ed4ad0fafd) and view example code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrta3n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontrol-value-accessor-connector.ts).

Please note that in the example that ControlValueAccessor is extended however that is not necessary. Also note that you may need to add formControl input if the control is not passed by name but by an instance.